# Jquery search on matching elements

Tags: jquery

I am implementing a keystroke-based search on visible elements in a div (airports that fall under a country).  In other words, on each key-up event, I hide all elements that don't have the matching phrase (case insensitive) in the text.

One more catch, search can only be done on elements that match the country id.

The html (C# Razor) is:

```
<div class="airport" id="airport-c@(airport.CountryId)-" name="airport-a@(airport.AirportId)-">
  <a ...etc>
    @airport.Airport <span class="airport-country">@airport.Country</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

I have this javascript to hide elements that don't match the country id, but I need to extend this to include the search match, and I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

```
$('[id^="airport-c"][id!="airport-c' + countryId + '-"]').hide();
```

Comment: i'm not sure how c# razor works. how does the user enter a search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be something like this:

```
$("a:contains('"+your_search_term+"')", "#airport-c" + countryId + "-");
```

Above statement will match any `<a>` element which contains your search term, which is inside the div with id `#airport-c" + countryId + "-"`

See [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/XFpwC/) .

Comment: Thanks for the demo.  Unfortunately the results are not case insensitive.  My requirement is also for the reverse case (i.e. select non-matching elements in order to hide them).

Comment: I wrapped in a "not" and implemented a custom contains function.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a `data-` attribute and use the Attribute Contains Selector. For example.

```
<p>
    <input type="text" id="q"/>
</p>
<ul>
    <li data-name="one">One</li>
    <li data-name="two">Two</li>
    <li data-name="three">Three</li>
    <li data-name="four">Four</li>
</ul>

$('#q').on('keyup', function(){
  $('li[data-name*="' + $('#q').val() + '"]').css('color', 'red');
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/f8dBv/).

Or if you can't/don't want to change the markup, you could use the contains selector.

```
$("li:contains('" + $('#q').val() + "')").css('color', 'red');
```

Comment: Not sure what's going on, but when I test that fiddler demo, I'm getting weird results.  Typing 't' is fine, then change it to 'tt', no change.  Delete all and type 'o' and everything highlights.  (Chrome and FF)

Comment: My bad, there is no code to un-highlight non-matching results.